# How to add JButton on JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jscrollpane

Hi i am trying to make a desktop application in swing here i am using jscrollpane. i want to add multipul button in jscrollpane. i am able to add only single button there how can i do this

My code is given below

```
 public class AddingToJScrollPane {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tabbed Pane Sample");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
    JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(label);

    JButton jButton1 = new JButton("Hello");
     JButton jButton2 = new JButton("Hello");

    jScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jScrollPane.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
    jScrollPane.getViewport().add(jButton1,jButton2);

    frame.add(jScrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.setSize(400, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Updated code

```
public class AddingToJScrollPane {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tabbed Pane Sample");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
panel.setLayout( new GridLayout() );
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
    JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);

    JButton jButton1 = new JButton("Hello");
     JButton jButton2 = new JButton("He");

   // jScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jScrollPane.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
   // jScrollPane.getViewport().add(panel);

    frame.add(jScrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(jButton1);
     panel.add(jButton2);
    frame.setSize(400, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

How can i achieve my desired output
Thanks in advance

Comment: _"How can i achieve my desired output "_ What exactly _is_ your desired output?

Comment: Edit your post to show what you tried. _Don't_ remove the current code. Just write **EDIT** below what you have, then post your new code below it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49301/discussion-between-user3377703-and-peeskillet)

Comment: *"How can i achieve my desired output"*  Copy/paste the part of your question where you ***describe*** the desired output.

Answer (score 8):

Add the buttons to a panel with suitable layout (e.g. `GridLayout` or `FlowLayout`).  Add the panel to the scroll pane.

Comment: i did this  and able to get multiple button but they are not coming in appropriate manner

Comment: 1) I'm not your 'dear'.  2) The stated problem is 'get more than one button into a scroll pane', so it **is** solved. 3) If you expect me to be able to solve the layout problem not knowing what layout was used, or what the intended affect is, you must think I'm some sort of magical wizard.  I'm not.

Comment: for natural scrolling to change intereg value in setUnitIncrement for derived JScrollBars from JScrollPane